# How to display price of an item based on the second select box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have a previous question like this but it only applies to 2 select boxes so here I'm asking again if someone can help me with 3 select boxes. I have trouble displaying the price of an item based on the selection of a select box. I have 2 tables namely items and item_details. items table has columns item_id and item_name only. item_details table has columns item_details_id, item_id(fk from items table) item_size and price.

I can display the corresponding items_details on the second select box of the item based on the first select box.

HTML

```
<td>
    <select name="item" class="form-control select2" id ="item">
       <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Item</option>
        @foreach($items as $key => $i)
         <option value="{!!$key!!}">{!!$i!!}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</td>

<td>
    <select name="item_details" class="form-control" id="item_details" >
    </select>       
</td>

<td>
    <select name="price" class="form-control" id="price" >
    </select>       
</td>
```

ItemController

```
public function findItemDetails($id)
{
  $details = DB::table("item_details")
  ->where("item_id",$id)
  ->lists("item_size","id");
  return json_encode($details);
}
```

JS

```
$('select[name="item"]').on('change', function() {
var itemID = $(this).val();
if(itemID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/findItemDetails/ajax/'+itemID,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
            $('select[name="item_details"]').empty();
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $('select[name="item_details"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
            });
        },
        error:function(){
        }
    });
}else{
    $('select[name="item_details"]').empty();
}
```

});

Routes

```
Route::get('findItemDetails/ajax/{id}',array('as'=>'findItemDetails',
        'uses'=>'ItemController@findItemDetails'));
```

I provided all the information needed to make 2 select boxes function but when i tried to search for topics about dynamic boxes that involves 3 select boxes i couldn't find any. I'm new to javascript and laravel, so i tried to duplicate my first code and changed the variables if by any chance i could display the price on the 3rd box but nothing works. Heres what i have.

ItemController

```
public function findPrice($id)
{
  $itemdetails = DB::table("itemdetails")
  ->lists("price","id");
  return json_encode($itemdetails);
}
```

JS

```
$('select[name="item_details"]').on('change', function() {
var itemdetailsID = $(this).val();
if(itemdetailsID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/findPrice/ajax/'+itemdetailsID,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
            $('select[name="price"]').empty();
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $('select[name="price"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
            });
        },
        error:function(){
        }
    });
}else{
    $('select[name="price"]').empty();
}
```

});

Routes

```
Route::get('findPrice/ajax/{id}',array('as'=>'findPrice',
        'uses'=>'ItemController@findPrice'));
```